# Javascript function just works on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

Let me introduce another of IE's tricks!

Today, to my surprise I have the inverse situation. I have something working well on Internet Explorer and not on FireFox and Chrome! Seriously, does someone know why this is functional in IE and not on other browsers?
This code seems useless, but that's because I've isolated the problem. Here we go:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function redirectFuncionTest(value){
document.getElementById(value).click();
return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="start redirectFuncionTest"
        onclick="redirectFuncionTest('idLink')" />
    <a id="idLink" name="namelink" href="http://www.google.com"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help? Is there another way to do something like that?

Thanks for read!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I programmatically click on an element in firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809057/how-do-i-programmatically-click-on-an-element-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with your help i wrote something like this snippet who solved my problem...

```
<html>                                                                  
 <head>                                                                  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
 <script type="text/javascript">                                         
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btn_go").click(function(){
   $(location).attr('href',"http://www.google.com");

   });
 });                                    
 </script>                                                               
 </head>                                                                 
 <body>       
    <input type="button" id="btn_go" value="go" />
 </body>                                                                 
 </html>
```

Thanks for everyone, you guys are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

The `click()` method only exists in IE.

Instead, you can write `location = document.getElementById(value).href`

Comment: Note, this will bypass any click listeners attached to the <a>, which may or may not be intended.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult, see the previous question on the same topic,

[How do I programmatically click a link with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902713/how-do-i-automatically-click-a-link-with-javascript)

I recommend using jQuery or some other library if it is available. Alternatively, just use

```
window.location = link.href;
```

And bypass the link

Comment: @mplungjan It's never "needed", it is however easier and less error prone and browser agnostic. Making everything simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Here [How do I programmatically click on an element in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809057/how-do-i-programmatically-click-on-an-element-in-firefox)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
if(typeof HTMLElement!='undefined'&&!HTMLElement.prototype.click) {
HTMLElement.prototype.click=function() {
var evt = this.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, this.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
this.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
}
function redirectFuncionTest(value){
  document.getElementById(value).click();
  return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="start redirectFuncionTest"
    onclick="redirectFuncionTest('idLink')" />
  <a id="idLink" name="namelink" href="http://www.google.com"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So who downvoted the actual solution to the question asked without commenting?

Answer (score 0):

click() is not a JavaScript method. Probably IE implements it as a custom IE method.

Some libraries such as jQuery have that method.

[click() (javascript) method is not working in FF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471051/click-javascript-method-is-not-working-in-ff)

Answer (score -2):

**Culprit**

```
document.getElementById...
```

is your culprit here, it's not very cross-browser safe. I know it makes learning VERY hard.

**Solution : Javascirpt Utility Function**

[Here's a cross-browser solution.](http://codingrecipes.com/documentgetelementbyid-on-all-browsers-cross-browser-getelementbyid)

```
  function get_object(id) {
   var object = null;
   if (document.layers) {
    object = document.layers[id];
   } else if (document.all) {
    object = document.all[id];
   } else if (document.getElementById) {
    object = document.getElementById(id);
   }
   return object;
  }
```

**Alternate Solution: JQuery**

If you'd really rather have a simpler solution, give JQuery a quick glance. It's something new to learn, but it is much more cross-browser compatable than out-of-the-box javascript.

Comment: No browser less than 15 years old has any problem with `getElementById`

Comment: Only IE allows to use ID on a named button without ID

Comment: document.getElementById() nowadays is safe in every browser, and is what jQuery uses to get elements by ID too, since you are advising to use a JS library only for retrieving elements by ID, the simpler of the tasks.

Comment: The code you posted works wonderfully with Netscape 4 and IE 5. Very useful ;)

Comment: @SLaks: Close. Netscape 4 and IE 4, both released in 1997, didn't have `document.getElementById()`, and Netscape continued releasing 4.x versions into the 2000s. But yes, you're obviously right that no browser relevant today doesn't have support for it, although it's worth mentioning that the implementation is flawed in IE up to and including version 7.

Comment: @Tim: How is it flawed? Does it return `name`d elements?