# Handling "onclick" event with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling, dom-events

This is really straight forward but I'm still fairly new to JavaScript and just found JSFiddle.  I'm trying to find the element with the `getElementById()` to disable and enable a button.  What am I missing?

```
<form name="frm" > 
  <div id="chkObj"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="setChkBx" onclick="basicList.modifyAndEnableButton(this)"></input>        
</div>
<div id="Hello"> 
    <input type="button" name="btn" value="Hello"></input>        
  </div>
</form>
```

This is a list that I am using to add checkboxes because there is going to be more than one:

```
 var basicList = {
    'items': {},
    'modifyAndEnableButton': function(obj1) {
        var element = document.getElementsByName("btn");
        if (obj1.checked == true && element.getAttribute('disabled') == false) {
            element.getAttribute('disabled') = true;
            this.addRecord(obj2);
        } else if (element.getAttribute('disabled') == true) {
            if (hasItems == false) {
                element.getAttribute('disabled') = false;
            }
        } 
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Arandolph0/E9zvc/3/

Comment: To downvoters, consider that currently the Google search for JavaScript click's top results are for w3schools and jQuery. I discuss this in meta [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177988/how-can-stack-overflow-users-be-encouraged-to-use-jquery-only-when-appropriate/178048#178048).

Comment: OP, if I were you I'd revert your edit. It makes your problem a lot more specific and a lot less applicable to the general audience, moreover, it contains a lot of syntax errors that you should probably look into and kind of ruins some of it.

Comment: dose every checkbox have a button associated with it?

Comment: No. Sorry about all the edits I realized after I posted that jsfiddle didn't save my changes and that included the code that was unedited. Please overlook.

Comment: @AprilRandolph Would you mind if I revert it to the original edit which I find more useful and generally applicable (and generally a better question)?

Comment: What is the rush button supposed to do?

Comment: So it's supposed to act as a faucet would... the checkbox is checked and the button is enabled the checkbox is un-checked and the button is disabled.

Comment: By the way the original didn't ask enough to specify functionality concerns that are what needs to be addressed.

Comment: Try this... http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/Tpbdd/ If i understood you correctly this is it, that you want...

Comment: Thanks. Is 'e.target.checked' is that jquery? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: No, checked is just html attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/checkbox

Answer (score 87, accepted):

All browsers support this ([see example here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick):

```
mySelectedElement.onclick = function(e){
    //your handler here
}
```

However, sometimes you want to add a handler (and not change the same one), and more generally when available you should use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) (needs shim for IE8-)

```
mySelectedElement.addEventListener("click",function(e){
   //your handler here
},false);
```

Here is a working example:

```
var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
button.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    button.disabled = "true";
},false);
```

And html:

```
<button id='myButton'>Hello</button>
```

#### [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/74Ydj/)

Here are some useful resources:

- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) on mdn
- [The click event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-click) in the DOM specification
- [Click example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Getting_Started#Example%3a_Catching_a_mouse_click)  in the MDN JavaScript tutorial

Comment: @AprilRandolph You have a typo. Please don't ask me to fix your typos in your variable names again :) You can [use the Chrome developer tools to find these yourself](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/part1/).

Comment: @AprilRandolph Again, check my code, this is _still_ a typo. Your event name is wrong. Again, you can [use the developer tools to check which events are fired on an element](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#monitoring_events) . Happy coding! :)

Comment: what is `false` in `addEventListener`?

Comment: useCaptutr you can ignore it safely if you are not sure what capture is

Answer (score 6):

Benjamin's answer covers quite everything. However you need a delegation model to handle events on elements that were added dynamically then

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.id == "abc") {
        alert("Clicked");
    }
});
```

For IE7/IE8

```
document.attachEvent('onclick', function (e) {
    if (window.event.srcElement == "abc") {
        alert("Clicked");
    }
});
```

Comment: Sharing Knowledge :-) I try to advocate delegation so that people don't come across those nightmares on why an event is not working. It personally happened to me until I knew about it. Is there anything bad about delegation?

Comment: in addEventListener you should change `e.srcElement.id` to `e.target.id` and in attachEvent `e.srcElement.id` to `window.event.srcElement.id`

Comment: @Givi Thanks but they all worked in all the browsers. (Latest Versions, plus IE 10 in IE7/8 mode)

Comment: Gotcha! MDN says this event.target is the original element the event happened to. However, Internet Explorer calls it event.srcElement. In fact, Chrome and Safari started setting both. You can do this for maximum compatibility

Answer (score 3):

You have a `Error` here

`btnRush` should be `Rushbtn`

This is a example of cross browser event's I just made (not tested) )

```
var addEvent = function( element, type, callback, bubble ) { // 1
    if(document.addEventListener) { // 2
        return element.addEventListener( type, callback, bubble || false ); // 3
    }
    return element.attachEvent('on' + type, callback ); // 4
};



var onEvent = function( element, type, callback, bubble) { // 1
    if(document.addEventListener) { // 2
        document.addEventListener( type, function( event ){ // 3
            if(event.target === element || event.target.id === element) { // 5
                callback.apply(event.target, [event]); // 6
            }
        }, bubble || false);
    } else {
        document.attachEvent( 'on' + type, function( event ){ // 4 
            if(event.srcElement === element || event.srcElement.id === element) { // 5
                callback.apply(event.target, [event]); // 6
            }
        });
    }

};
```

> ## Steps

1. Create a function that accepts 4 values ( self explaining )
2. Check if the browser supports `addEventListener`
3. Add event on the element
4. else add event on the element for older IE
5. Check that the (clicked) element is = to the passed element
6. call the callback function pass the element as this and pass the event

   The `onEvent` is used for event delegation.
   The `addEvent` is for your standard event.

   here's how you can use them

> The first 2 are for dynamically added elements

```
onEvent('rushBtn', 'click', function(){
    alert('click')
});

var rush = document.getElementById('rushBtn');

onEvent(rush, 'click', function(){
    alert('click');
});

// Standard Event
addEvent(rush, 'click', function(){
    alert('click');
});
```

Event Delegation is this basically.

Add a click event to the document so the event will fire whenever & wherever then you check the element that was clicked on to see if it matches the element you need. this way it will always work.

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E9zvc/4/)