# I have 2 radio buttons if 1 is selected another 1 should automatically disabled before click the sumbit button.How can i achieve this by javascript?

Tags: javascript

```html
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
```

If a select 1 radio button other should disable automatically before i click submit.How can i achieve this using javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should provide some code of what you have tried so far to solve the problem. Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Have you tried something ? Show us your effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript onclick event handling with pure JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633152/javascript-onclick-event-handling-with-pure-javascript) and [Disabling and enabling a html input button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831601/disabling-and-enabling-a-html-input-button)

Comment: Why will you disable it? With a radio button you can only select one of the options...

Answer (score 0):

If you check any of the radio inputs, the another one will be disabled automatically.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.addEventListener('change', function(){
  Array.from(elems).find(c => !c.checked).disabled = true;
  console.log(`You selected: ${this.value}`);
}));
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
```