# Add hover effect on click and remove again if clicked again

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I have made a product block with the option to see on hover a nice effect but i would like to see the hover effect which I am seeing on hover to be seen on click of the div but I don't know how I can achieve that.

The only thing I want is to have it completely in css/sass or Javascript if it cannot be done with Javascript or css/sass then jQuery is ok.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #c8cfdc;
  color: #363636;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.blocks_container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
}

.block {
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.product_block {
  width: 31%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 340px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.product_block .product_header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.43s cubic-bezier(0.32, 1.259, 0.375, 1.15);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.43s cubic-bezier(0.32, 1.259, 0.375, 1.15);
  transition: transform 0.43s cubic-bezier(0.32, 1.259, 0.375, 1.15);
  transition: transform 0.43s cubic-bezier(0.32, 1.259, 0.375, 1.15), -webkit-transform 0.43s cubic-bezier(0.32, 1.259, 0.375, 1.15);
}
.product_block .product_header .product_heart {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.product_block .product_header .product_heart img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.product_block .product_header .product_tag {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #3b4068;
  padding: 4px 15px;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.product_block .product_header .product_shop {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.product_block .product_header .product_shop img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.product_block .product_img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
  height: 260px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 50% 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 900ms ease;
}
.product_block .product_info {
  transform: translate(0px, 200px);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.product_block .product_info .product_title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.product_block .product_info .product_subtitle {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #999;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.product_block .product_info .product_price {
  font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.product_block .product_info .product_price span {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #fc7070;
  padding-left: 9px;
}
.product_block:hover {
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  background-color: #3b4068;
  color: #fff;
}
.product_block:hover .product_header {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.product_block:hover .product_header .product_tag {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #3b4068;
}
.product_block:hover .product_img {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.03);
  transform: scale(1.03);
  background-position: 30% 30%;
  width: 40%;
  -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
.product_block:hover .product_info {
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  transform: translate(0px, -150px);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks_container">
  <div class="block product_block rem" id="red">
    <div class="product_header">
      <div class="product_heart"> <img src="http://calleriphotographer.it/loving.svg"/></div>
<!--       <div class="product_tag">Waffle</div> -->
      <div class="product_shop"><img src="http://calleriphotographer.it/cart.svg"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product_img" style="background-image: url('http://calleriphotographer.it/nike.png')"></div>
    <div class="product_info">
      <h3 class="product_title">nike</h3>
      <h5 class="product_subtitle">Air Max Tavas SD</h5>
      <p class="product_price">$160.00<span>$200.00</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to edit it in codepen with sass click below

[my codepen link](http://codepen.io/amirhanif/pen/dvpRBM)

Comment: maybe this answer can be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633152/javascript-onclick-event-handling-with-pure-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need an active state for you **.product_block** element

**CSS**

```
.product_block.active:hover {
    transition: all 300ms ease;
    background-color: #3b4068;
    color: #fff;
}
.product_block.active:hover .product_header {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.product_block.active:hover .product_header .product_tag {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #3b4068;
}
.product_block.active:hover .product_img {
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.03);
    transform: scale(1.03);
    background-position: 30% 30%;
    width: 40%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(20deg);
}
.product_block.active:hover .product_info {
    transition: all 300ms ease;
    transform: translate(0px, -150px);
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.product_block');

elem.addEventListener("click", function(){
        this.classList.add('active');
})
```

P.S. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/acunwhvh/)

Comment: i see it is adding the class active but i also need to have it to be a toggle so if i click again it removes the hover effect how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Toggle logic

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.product_block');

elem.addEventListener("click", function(){
   if(this.classList.contains('active')) {
      this.classList.remove('active');
   } else {
      this.classList.add('active');
   }    
})
```

Comment: i have one question, if i want to add more blocks and click on them as well the effect is not working at all it is just working for one block? why is that

Answer (score 1):

You need to query all items and then iterate over them

Like that:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.product_block');

for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i = i +1) {
    elems[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
       if(this.classList.contains('active')) {
           this.classList.remove('active');
       } else {
       this.classList.add('active');
       }    
    })
}
```

Comment: againnn your help is really appreciated it workss :)