# Html,css3, jquery how to create on click event

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

I want to make a button inside auto generated block to change overflow from `hidden` to `auto`.

I created recursive responsive auto-grid in Less, css like this:

```css
.container {
  .container-fixed();
  [class*='col-'] {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .make-grid(@container-xs);
  .make-grid(@container-sm);
  .make-grid(@container-md);
  .make-grid(@container-lg);
}

.container-fixed(@gap: @grid-gap-width) {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: (@gap / 2);
  padding-right: (@gap / 2);
}

.generate-columns(@container-width;
@number-cols;
@i: 1) when (@i =< @number-cols) {
  .col-@{i} {
    @single-width: @container-width / @number-cols - 0.5;
    width: @i * @single-width; // 800px
  }
  .generate-columns(@container-width;
  @number-cols;
  @i + 1);
}

.make-grid(@container-width) {
  @media(min-width: @container-width) {
    width: @container-width;
    .generate-columns(@container-width, @grid-c);
  }
}

[class*='col-'] {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 250px;
  background: @color-h;
  display: block;
  margin: 1px;
  color: @color-text;
  position: relative;
}
```

And now I have long text in HTML inside one of blocks no matter which one, eg. col-9 where is part hidden because I used `overflow:hidden;`.

What I would like to do is to create a button and on click to change from `overflow:hidden;` to `overflow: auto;`.

My question is how to do that, to change from `hidden` to `auto`, on click and again to return back to previous state on new click.

I tried something like this but that is not good:

Less - >

```css
[class*='col-'] {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 250px;
  background: @color-h;
  display: block;
  margin: 1px;
  color: @color-text;
  position: relative;
  .show {
    overflow: auto;
  }
}
```

JS - >

```js
var content = document.getElementsByClassName("[class*='col-']");
var button = document.getElementbyID("show");

button.onclick = function() {
    if (content.className == "show") {
        content.className= "";
        button.inerHTML = "Read";
    } else {
        content.className="show";
        button.inerHTML = "Close";
    }
};
```

html - >

```html
<div class="col-9">
    <a id="button-show">Read</a>
    <script src="js/read.js"></script>
    <p> some long text ........ </p>
 </div>
```

I hope I am clear enough, what I want to do.

Comment: Your onlick function is incorrect - see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633152/javascript-onclick-event-handling-with-pure-javascript

Comment: Problem is here: "content.className" where content is object array but you trying access without index it should: "content[index].className". Also you have no such className like "[class*='col-']" so you should use querySelectorAll to select like CSS style.

Answer (score 0):

<-- language: lang-javascript -->

```
$("#button-show").click(function(){
    $(".col-9").toggleClass("show")
})
```

<-- -->

so whenever you click the button, it will add or remove the class `show` on your elements with the `col-9` classnames

Comment: yea but that is only for .col-9, is there a solution for rest columns , or i have to create for col-6, col-12 ... etc. Or there is an uniform code for all generated columns ?

Comment: you can just add a classname for your target elements to make it uniform :) let's say `<div class="col-9 contents">` and just target it with `$(".contents").toggleClass("show")`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to toggle the contents between show and hide. Here is an example

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button-show").click(function(){
        $("#show").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
[class*='col-'] {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 250px;
    background: @color-h;
    display: block;
    margin: 1px;
    color: @color-text;
    position: relative;
}


    #show {
        overflow: auto;
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-9">
    <a id="button-show">Read</a>
    <p id="show"> some long text ........ </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems in your code.

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements (A.K.A. array), so your `content.className` is wrong as you accesing the array `className` property (which is non-existant) instead of the `className` property of each element inside the array. You have to iterate the array and access each element individually. Also, you are not accesing by class, but by selector (There's no class `[class*='col-']`, but class `col-1`, `col-2`, etc...). To select with selectors you have to use `querySelector`, which selects one element, or `querySelectorAll` which selects all elements.

Also, to hide an element you don't have to change `overflow`. `overflow` is for scrollbars. You have to change the display property to `display: none` and also as the class `show` is not a child element, it needs an `&` character:

```
[class*='col-'] {
  text-align: center;
  [...CSS THINGYS...]
  position: relative;
  &.show { // Note the & before the dot
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Your code don't has any jQuery actually. Is plain JS.

Also, the best way to attach events to HTML elements is via `addEventListener`, so:

```
var content = document.querySelectorAll("[class*='col-']");
var button = document.getElementbyID("show");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var anyShown = false;
    content.forEach(function(element) {
        if (element.className == "show") {
            anyShown = true;
            element.className= "";
        } else {
            element.className="show";
        }
    });
    if (anyShown) {
        button.inerHTML = "Read";
    } else {
        button.inerHTML = "Close";
    }
});
```

If you want it in a more jQuery way you can do this, which do the same as above, but way shorter:

```
$("#show").on("click", function() {
    if ($("[class*='col-']").hasClass("show")) {
        $("#show").html("Read");
    } else {
        $("#show").html("Close");
    }
    $("[class*='col-']").toggleClass("show");
});
```

*Relevant info:*

- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [getelementsbyclassname](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)
- [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Less "&" operator](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature)
- [jQuery hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)
- [jQuery toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

JQ:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
  $("p3").toggle();
 });
});
```

CSS:

```
[class*='col-'] {
  text-align: center;
  overflow:auto;
  height: 250px;
  background: @color-h;
  margin: 1px;
  color: @color-text;
  position: relative;
  .border-radius(10px);
    p3 {
        margin: 10px ;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 95%;
        text-align: justify;
        display: none; 
        }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-9">
<button>Read</button>
<h1>TITLE</h1>
<p>some tekst.</p>
<p3>Tekst i want to hide ....</p3>
</div>
```

Comment: but with this i have one button that toggle all p3 in every block on same page, and i don't want that i want to have separate button for every block, so this is working but only for one article ...