# Is there any way to select elements in loop

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down menu created from li elements and each of them has a unique id. Instead of writing 4 different variables I want to create one loop (if possible and has sense) but I'm encountering a problem. After clicking on the particular li, the program should change the innerhtml with this li value.

```
function calories_calculator() {
  const list = new Array(3);
  list[0] = "1";
  list[1] = "2"; /////// those numbers are id of li elements
  list[2] = "3";
  list[3] = "4";
  const array = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    const f = document.getElementById(list[i]).onclick;
    if (true) {
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = list[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the html code where you defined your dropdown menu?

Comment: Note that you are defining an array with the size of 3, but are putting 4 elements inside it, this defeats the performance gain when declaring the size upfront

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```html
  <ul>
    <li id="id1"><button>aaaaa</button></li>
    <li id="id2"><button>bbbbb</button></li>
    <li id="id3"><button>ccccc</button></li>
    <li id="id4"><button>ddddd</button></li>
  </ul>
  <div></div>
</body>
<script>
 const elements = document.querySelectorAll('li')
 elements.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click' , () => {
   document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = element.textContent;
  })
 })
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactly, thank you. I'd like just to ask about for loop, is there any sense to use it while doing any action like the above ? I've come back to front end recently, still with loop attitude from python where I could do this kind of operations.

Comment: Yes you can. forEach() is just an easy way. Also you can use, map() because const elements is an array ( `console.log(elements)`  & you will see it). Even a while loop

Comment: I assume you know about arrow functions? In modern JS we can write `function(){}` as `() => {}`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a syntax issue with your "onclick" event handler. The onclick should be followed by an equal sign and then the function. I found this answer which might be useful:
[Handling "onclick" event with pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633152/handling-onclick-event-with-pure-javascript)