# Click action does not work against input file element on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

I get the input file element,  and try to click on it in js on Chrome console, but it does not work and the file upload dialog does not appear. How can I achieve this?
`document.getElementById("input_file").click();`

Comment: Do you want to click by javascript or you want to capture the click? You want to do some action on clicking "input_file" ?

Comment: You can't. It's a security feature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input

Comment: I want to click by javascript. @Pramod

Comment: Yes, there are many answers to your questions. You should have searched once in stackoverflow at least. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440832/generating-a-click-event-on-using-javascript or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906486/how-can-i-programmatically-invoke-an-onclick-event-from-a-anchor-tag-while-kee

Answer (score -2):

try with onClick:

```
document.getElementById("input_file").onclick = function(){
   //code for the action when clicked
};
```

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/ghP2Y/1/

Comment: I want to click on this element,not add a listener.

Comment: I don't think you can do it due to security reasons