# JavaScript Automaticly click a Button

Tags: javascript, button, automation, spotify

i know this is pretty simple but i dont get it done anyway... :(
I want the script to automaticly klick the playbutton on a spotify page (like this one: [Spotify Page](https://open.spotify.com/embed?uri=spotify%3Atrack%3A7pNRuxZ7vN5p8qw9Aoyfbq)).
So when the page is loaded the script should start the song by itself.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code, do you want it as an extension, or enter it in the console?

Comment: Take a look at user scripts, such as TamperMonkey for Chrome or Greasy Fork for Firefox. When you have some code you can come back and ask something specific.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278469/click-a-button-programmatically-js

Answer (score 0):

Clicks can be programmatically triggered. On this particular page the play button's ID is "play-button".

[jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#play-button").click();
})
```

[Vanilla JS](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp)

```
window.onload() = function() {
  document.getElementById("play-button").click();
}
```

Comment: window.onload = function() you don't want to call the onload