# Trigger a 'Click' on an Input field

Tags: javascript, events, input, event-handling, eventtrigger

I am trying to trigger a 'click' on an input field. However, am unable to get it to work with native javascript. No jquery solution please.

[Link to CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-leaf-kiojz?fontsize=14)

Code:

```
function triggerEvent(elem, event) {
  var clickEvent = new MouseEvent(event); // Create the event.
  console.log("dispatching now", elem, clickEvent);
  elem.dispatchEvent(clickEvent); // Dispatch the event.
}

// var inp = document.getElementById("inp");
var label = document.getElementById("labelInp");
triggerEvent(label, "click");
```

I tried the solutions in other questions, however, none worked on an input field. Hence this question.

Update:

Added object with props for the `MouseEvent` to see if that helps, however, it doesn't.

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-resonance-zzjrs

Comment: None of the solutions work on input field. Hence the question asking for triggering on an input field.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-bush-ihugc

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-jennings-nweud

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. Doesn't work on Firefox.

Comment: I see. That is not new: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809057/how-do-i-programmatically-click-on-an-element-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks again for looking into this. Unfortunately, the user lulian's solution also didn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22469115/434697

Comment: Can you post your actual attempts at using these solutions?

Comment: Please see the question update (bottom of the question) for an updated link to codesandbox.